# Не получается сделать Get запрос с proxy-сервера с аутентификатором Java

Tags: java, веб-программирование, proxy

```java
public String ss() {
    System.setProperty("jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes", "false");
    System.setProperty("jdk.http.auth.proxying.disabledSchemes", "false");
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().
            proxy(ProxySelector.of(new InetSocketAddress("130.185.126.159", 6774)))
            .authenticator(new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication () {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("host", "pass".toCharArray());
                }
            }).build();
    
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(java.net.URI.create("https://mycgsportal.com/MyCGS/CGSAccount/Login"))
            .GET()
            .build();
    HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    
    return response.headers().toString();
}
```

В ответе я получаю `407 Proxy Authentication Required`; описание к ошибке: `" proxy-authenticate=[Basic realm="Invalid proxy credentials or missing IP Authorization."]"`.